Find the number of layers in an *ome.tif file using tifffile package
Here are the standards for a pyramidal ome-tif file: https://docs.openmicroscopy.org/ome-model/5.6.3/ome-tiff/
These files are supported by the tifffile package in python: https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/tree/master
Here is the syntax of opening a specific level of one of these pyramidal ome-tif files from their readme: https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/ec6be6289db1b8b7327bb98816a764c95b9b7299/README.rst?plain=1#L678-L682
Here is code to make an ome-tif file to use for testing: https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/ec6be6289db1b8b7327bb98816a764c95b9b7299/README.rst?plain=1#L631-L674
I can't seem to find an easy way to just get the number of layers the file has. A simple solution is here:
simple_all_levels.py
from tifffile import imread, imwrite, TiffFile

f = 'temp.ome.tif'

# Make smaller versions of the big tiff
i = 0
while True:
  image = imread(f, series=0, level=i)
  imwrite(f"L{i}.{f}", image)
  i = i + 1
  print(i)

Just run this until it crashes, the last i that prints is the number of layers. But running until crashing is kinda dumb. After some peeping, I found this snippet:
get_layers_weird.py
from tifffile import imread, imwrite, TiffFile

f = 'temp.ome.tif'

tif = TiffFile(f)

list_of_pages = tif.pages.pages[0].pages.pages

print(len(list_of_pages))

This gets me the answer I want, but getting the length of an array of an accession, of an accession of an array's first member, which is an accession to the accession of a supplementary import seems too obfuscated to be the intended place for this information to be held.
Where should I look in the ome-tif for its number of levels?
EDIT: I did "my own research" using the following script and found len(tif.pages.keyframe.subifds) to be a slightly more bearable reference.
from tifffile import imread, imwrite, TiffFile

f = 'temp.ome.tif'

primitives = (bool, str, int, float, type(None))
prim_iters = (list, tuple, dict, set)

# Find out how to get "level" variable
tif = TiffFile(f)

# Stop criteria
list_of_pages = tif.pages.pages[0].pages.pages
subifds = tif.pages._keyframe.subifds
known_num_levels = 6
depth_limit = 6

tif_vars = [(f"tif.{k}",v) for k,v in vars(tif).items()]
depth = 0
depth_breadth = 0
while tif_vars:
  
  if depth_breadth == 0:
    depth_breadth = len(tif_vars)
    depth = depth + 1
    print(f"depth: {depth}")
    print(f"breadth: {depth_breadth}")

  if depth > depth_limit:
    break

  # print(tif_vars)
  tif_key, tif_var = tif_vars.pop(0)
  depth_breadth -= 1
  
  if type(tif_var) in primitives:
    print(f"primitive: {tif_key} : {tif_var}")
    if tif_var == known_num_levels:
      print(f"candidate: {tif_key} : {tif_var}")
    if tif_var in subifds:
      print(f"answer field: {tif_key} : {tif_var}")
  elif tif_var == list_of_pages:
    print(f"page key: {tif_key}")
  elif tif_key.endswith("parent"):
    print(f"parent: {tif_key}")
  elif tif_key == 'tif._fh._fh': # Crashes when used
    print(f"Skipping {tif_key}")
  elif str(type(tif_key)) == "<class '_io.BufferedReader'>":
    print(f"Skipping {tif_key} as a BufferedReader")
  elif hasattr(tif_var, "__dict__"):
    print(f"dict: {tif_key}")
    tif_vars += [(f"{tif_key}.{k}",v) for k,v in vars(tif_var).items()]
  elif hasattr(tif_var, "__dir__") and type(tif_var) not in prim_iters:
    print(f"dir: {tif_key}")
    tif_vars += [(f"{tif_key}.{k}", getattr(tif_var, k)) for k in dir(tif_var) if not callable(getattr(tif_var, k))]
  elif hasattr(tif_var, "__iter__"):
    print(f"iter: {tif_key}")
    tif_vars += [(f"{tif_key}[{i}]",tif_var_child) for i, tif_var_child in enumerate(tif_var)]
    if len(tif_var) == known_num_levels:
      print(f"candidate list: {tif_key} : {tif_var}")


Try len(TiffFile(filename).series[0].levels). That includes the full resolution base level.
